# How to end an IF block when there is no ELSE clause and continue with the indent levels

Tags: pug

While iterating through a list, I keep count and if it's an even item, I would like my output to be:

```
.row
  .col-md-6
     ...xxx...
       ...yyy...
```

else it should just be:

```
  .col-md-6  //note the indent is to be same as above, ie child of .row
     ...xxx...
       ...yyy...
```

The output should be repeating blocks of:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     ..
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
     ..
  </div>
</div>
```

My intended script is:

```
if even
  .row
end if  //is there such a statement?
    .col-md-6
      ...xxx...
        ...yyy...
```

What is the proper way of writing it without resorting to an `else` block and repeating its contents in the `even` block as well?

Comment: Could you please give us an example of what you are iterating over? What you are trying to do (exactly as you are trying it) probably isn't possible as each time the loop starts over it creates a new instance, starting at the same indent level at the previous one, but I am sure we can make something work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render 2 items on each loop, only rendering at all when it is even. Something like

```
for foo, i in bar
    if i % 2 === 0
        .row
            .col-md-6
                // whatever you want to do with foo

             - var foo2 = bar[i+1]
             if foo2
                .col-md-6
                    // whatever you want to do with foo2
```

Comment: Thanks, works for me.  It requires the `.col-md-6` contents to be repeated and I use a mixin to take care of that. The trick is to distinguish between logic indentation and mark-up indentation. The output of `if foo2` then clause is aligned at the same position of the `i` in `if foo2`.

Answer (score 0):

To break out of an `if` statement, just resume the indentation at the same level as the `if` statement in question. That will let the code proceed after the `if` statement.

```
- var even = true;
if even
    .row
.col-md-6
    ...xxx...
        ...yyy...
```

Produces:

```
<div class="row"></row>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <xxx>
        <yyy></yyy>
    </xxx>
</div>
```

If `even` is false, `<div class="row"></row>` is omitted from the output, but the rest of it still outputs.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me as I want the `.col-md-6` divs to be children of the `.row` div.

Answer (score 0):

Although Joe Lissner's answer is correct it does contain code duplication because you have to specify what you want to do with the item, twice per row. His answer also doesn't scale well for situations where you need more than two items per row.

Instead of using the [i+1] structure by Joe Lissner's I would suggest using a second loop to find all the items that have to fall into this row. This can be done using the following pattern:

```
- var itemsPerRow = 2; // This can be any positive number
each unused, i in list
  if (i % itemsPerRow == 0)
    .row
      each item, j in list
        if (j - i >= 0 && j -i < itemsPerRow)
          .col-md-6
             .. What you want to do with -item- ..
```

The line `if (j - i >= 0 && j -i < itemsPerRow)` makes sure that only the items that actually fall into that row get render.

This avoids code duplication because you only have to type `.. What you want to do with -item- ..` once.

The result looks like this

```
.row
  .col-md-6
  .col-md-6
.row
  .col-md-6
  .col-md-6
.row
  .col-md-6
  .col-md-6
```